# perl script not looking for text file

Tags: perl

I have a Perl script that is supposed to look for the text file I write in the command argument but, for whatever reason, it doesn't even acknowledge the existence of the text file I write in the argument, even though it is in the same folder.

This is where the code starts going haywire

```
my $filename = $ARGV[0];

if($filename == "") {
    print("[ERROR] Argument unavailable! use ./script.pl filename.txt\n");
    end;
} elsif (open (FILE, "<", $filename)) {
    print("[INFO] File $filename loaded successfully!\n\n");
    menu();
    close FILE;
} else{
    die("An error occured while opening the file: $!\n\n");
    end;
}
```

Comment: Add `use strict;` and `use warnings;`  - correct everything. `$filename == ""` isn't valid for example.

Comment: "it doesn't even acknowledge the existence of the text file I write in the argument" — How do you expect it to do that?

Comment: "the code starts going haywire" — That isn't a useful description of the behaviour

Comment: "I have a PERL Script" — https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq1#What's-the-difference-between-%22perl%22-and-%22Perl%22?

Comment: What is this `end` word? Never seen that before, is it a subroutine? Using numerical comparison on a string `== ""` will cast that string to a number, in this case `0`. You want `eq` for string equality. This will likely never trigger. As for a reason, `$!` should give you an error message. Perhaps you should include it in the question so we can know what it says

Comment: Your problem is that you are comparing the filename to the empty string using a numeric comparison operator. If your filename starts with digits and at least one of them is not a 0, it won't be numerically equal to the empty string, which evaluates to 0. But, ignore all that. The test you likely want is `defined $ARGV[0]` because you only care that the argument exists, not that it's a particular value.

Answer (score 1):

Always use

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

When writing Perl code. It will tell you when you do something wrong, and give you information that might otherwise be hard to find.

What do I get when I run your program with these pragmas on?

```
$ foo.pl asdasd
Argument "" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at foo.pl line 9.
Argument "asdasd" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at foo.pl line 9.
[ERROR] Argument unavailable! use ./script.pl filename.txt
```

Those warnings come from `use warnings`. Good thing we were using that! Here, I am told that using `==` for string comparisons is causing some issues.

What happens is that both the filename and the empty string `""` is being cast to numbers. Perl uses context for operators, and `==` forces Perl to use a numeric, scalar context. It assumes the arguments are supposed to be numbers, to it tries to coerce them into numbers. It will attempt to find a number at the beginning of the string, and if it doesn't find one, cast the value to `0`. So your comparison becomes:

```
if (0 == 0)
# equal to "foo.txt" == ""
```

Which is true. Hence the program never gets further than this.

The proper way to fix this particular problem is to use `eq`, the string equality comparison:

```
if ($file eq "")
```

Then it will check if the file name is the empty string. However, this is not the correct solution for you. Lets try it out, and use the test case that the user forgot the argument:

```
$ foo.pl
Use of uninitialized value $filename in string eq at foo.pl line 9.
[ERROR] Argument unavailable! use ./script.pl filename.txt
```

Why? Because in this case `$ARGV[0]` is not the empty string, it is `undef`, or uninitialized. It still sort of gets it right, since `undef eq ""` is true, but does give a warning that you are using the wrong method.

What you want to do here is just check if it exists. A new strategy:

```
if (@ARGV < 1)    # check for number of arguments to program
```

You can also adopt a file test, and check if the file exists:

```
if ( ! -e $file)
```

However, the simpler way to handle those cases is to just use a proper open statement:

```
open my $fh, "<", $file or die "Cannot open '$file': $!";
```

Which will then tell you if the file did not exist. This is the idiomatic way to open files in Perl: Three argument open with explicit open mode to prevent code injection, lexical file handle, and handling exceptions and reporting the error.

If I were to write your program, I would write it as:

```
if (@ARGV < 1) {
    die "Usage: $0 <filename>";   # $0 is your program's filename
}
my $file = shift;     # default shift uses @ARGV, or @_ inside a sub, this is a common Perl idiom
open my $fh, "<", $file or die "Cannot open '$file': $!";
menu();               # your menu subroutine, I assume...
close $fh;
```